# libgdx sqlite select *

Tags: sqlite, libgdx

В бд имеется несколько строк, формата id,login,password
Удалось прочитать только одну строку из БД. Как получить все остальные?
Сам запрос выдает несколько строк, проверил

С помощью cursor.getString(1) - выдает логин первой строки
cursor.getString(2) - выдает пароль первой строки

К слову, ещё интересует как вызывать процедуры

```
dbHandler = DatabaseHandlerFactory.getNewDatabaseHandler(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, DATABASE_CREATE, null);
    dbHandler.setupDatabase();
    dbHandler.openOrCreateDatabase();
    dbHandler.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    DatabaseCursor cursor;
    cursor = dbHandler.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PLAYERS);
    addText(cursor.getString(1));
    dbHandler.closeDatabae();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean b = cursor.next();
    while (b) {
        addText(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));
        b = cursor.next();
    }
```